# making a comment page

Tags: asp.net

i want to make a comment page but i don't know where to start or how  to do this. The member of my page must make a comment about videos, articles  etc. all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to examine your system usage / requirements carefully.   If it is an internal only site then your worries about Spam, etc. are less important.  However if it is public facing, do you users need to register to leave a comment, etc.  Spam becomes a real problem.  You then need to look into [cross-site scripting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), etc.

It is a really good idea to tackle the security / spam issues from the outset.  Then other questions you need to think about are what is your data store, where will you bee saving the comments.  Whilst there is no excuse for poor design, only finally, or even after going live, look at what caching could be used to improve performance.  To start with performance may be good enough, but over time you may need to profile your site to see any slow points, etc.

Comment: Thanks man it is really andvance for me that you said. i want to know basically how to make a comment page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming some knowledge of SQL Server and ASP.Net here, so please let us know the level of help required.

At a basic level you would need to create a table that has the required fields for a comment.

For example

- commentId - primary key
- memberId - foreign key to the member table
- postId - foreign key to your posts (or videos etc)
- creation_date
- modified_date
- comment - the text of the comment.

Your comment system should implement a Captcha - e.g. http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnetnewfeatures.aspx

If you would allow non-members to comment, add fields for email etc.

Then when you render your post / video pages, you'd also render comments which match the postId. Member name would be linked from your members table via memberId.

Of course, you will need to look after security, optimization, caching etc.

Comment: As you said after creating tables etc. what i am suppose to do to show  the posts that in the my database to people. Or what controller i must use to show posts.

Comment: +1. @thrillercd: Well, as slomojo pointed out, you should already have a page that displays videos, posts et cetera. Retrieve the related comments to the already shown items via LINQ or whatever database access technique you are using. If my comment or slomojo's answer is not helpful, you need to add more details about what the current status of your project is, what expierence you got and what database technology you are using

Answer (score 0):

@Thrillercd, your question is quite a general one. I would suggest you to look into some books / tutorials on how to do this. You can get more helpful resources at www.asp.net. There is one open source application called BlogEngine that I think can help you, since your site sounds like blog/community site (Link: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/BlogEngine.NET.aspx). Download it, study it, and you will have some basic understanding on how to build your site :)